# Fetch API "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm trying to pull in images using the Pixabay API. I have a input field and i'm taking that value and interpolating it in the url string. I'm able to pull i'm getting the response back successfully. When I try to loop through the array and pull in the images it's saying "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined". I'm not sure what's going on? Here is my code:

```js
const imgForm = document.querySelector("#search-form");
imgForm.addEventListener("submit", fetchImages);

function fetchImages(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const searchTerm = document.querySelector(".search").value;
  fetch(`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=8772164-4f816aa8fc1fc3045290454a0&q=${searchTerm}&image_type=photo&pretty=true`)
  .then((response) => {return response.json(); })
  .then((resp => {
    console.log(resp);
    let hitsArray = resp.data;
    showImages(hitsArray);
  }))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function showImages(hitsArray) {
  const results = document.querySelector(".results");
  console.log(results);
  
  let output = '<div class="container">';
  hitsArray.forEach((imgData) => {
    output += `
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="${imgData.hits.largeImageURL}"/>
  </div>
`;
  });
  document.querySelector('.results').innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<form id="search-form">
  <input type="text" class="search">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div class="results"></div>
```

Here is the actual demo I'm working on: 
https://codepen.io/Brushel/pen/KeOLRg?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response does not have a `data` property - rather, it has a `hits` property with the array you're looking for. Another problem is that the argument of the function passed to `forEach` is the array element being iterated over - instead of

```
imgData.hits.largeImageURL
```

just access the `largeImageURL` property:

```
imgData.largeImageURL
```

```js
const imgForm = document.querySelector("#search-form");
imgForm.addEventListener("submit", fetchImages);

function fetchImages(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const searchTerm = document.querySelector(".search").value;
  fetch(`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=8772164-4f816aa8fc1fc3045290454a0&q=${searchTerm}&image_type=photo&pretty=true`)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((resp => {
      let hitsArray = resp.hits;
      showImages(hitsArray);
    }))
    .catch(err => console.log('err:' + err));
}

function showImages(hitsArray) {
  const results = document.querySelector(".results");

  let output = '<div class="container">';
  hitsArray.forEach((imgData) => {
    output += `
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="${imgData.largeImageURL}"/>
  </div>
`;
  });
  document.querySelector('.results').innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<form id="search-form">
  <input type="text" class="search">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div class="results"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for well explanation for where I went wrong. That really helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `let hitsArray = resp.data;`

when it should be `let hitsArray = resp;`

There is no `data` property on the response.